# how to replace all values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I need to replace all values of pandas dataframe in a fast way.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep="\s*,", header=None)
cross_tab1 = pd.crosstab(data[0], data[1], rownames=['data0'], colnames=['data1'])
```

after that I want to take all values from data frame and add noise to all. I need something to make this possible `data.values = data.values + np.random.normal(0, 2.0)` Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

if you want a line as close as possible to `data.values = data.values + np.random.normal(0, 2.0)` then you might try something like:

```
data.update(data.values + np.random.normal(0, 2.0))
```

you could also look at apply, applymap, or transform

Comment: Actually, it didnt work for me. I used this `cross_tab1.update(cross_tab1.values+np.random.normal(0, 2.0, size=cross_tab1.size).reshape(cross_tab1.shape))`.  values did not change/

Comment: I tested that line and it worked for me. There might be another issue under all of this. Perhaps the cross tab is returning a copy and you wanted the original data to be modified?

Comment: Yes, i need modified original data. I checked it again, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: does it change cross_tab1? It's strange that it works for me and not you